# jQuery 'scroll();' animate doesn't restore

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate an class that appear and disappear on scroll.

However opacity works only on first scroll up and on scroll down it doesn't restore opacity back to 0... Anyone can help me please?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
        $('header').addClass('shortResize');
        $('.shortResize').animate({ 'opacity': '1' });
        $('section#contentWrap').addClass('contentWrap-margin');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('shortResize');
        $('.shortResize').css('opacity', '0');
        $('section#contentWrap').removeClass('contentWrap-margin');
    }
});
```

EDIT (html piece):

```
<header>
    <a id="logo" href="index.php"></a>
</header>
```

EDIT (css piece):

```
    header {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(61, 61, 61, .9) 50%, rgba(76, 76, 76, .9) 50%);
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;

    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

a#logo {
    background: url(../img/logo.png);
    width: 629px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

.shortResize {
    position: fixed !important;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    z-index: 33;
}

.contentWrap-margin {
    margin-top: 160px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML block?

Comment: Hmmm sure, but there's not much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this?

**UPDATE**

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
            $('header').addClass('shortResize');
            $('.shortResize').stop().animate({ 'opacity': '1' });
            $('section#contentWrap').addClass('contentWrap-margin');
        } else {
            console.log($(this).scrollTop());
            $('header').removeAttributes();
            $('section#contentWrap').removeClass('contentWrap-margin');
        }
    });



    jQuery.fn.removeAttributes = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var attributes = $.map(this.attributes, function (item) {
                return item.name;
            });
            var img = $(this);
            $.each(attributes, function (i, item) {
                img.removeAttr(item);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't remove attribute style at all :(

Comment: UPDATE: It does remove it if I manually remove class that is left in there... here is image. Why "class" remain there if class name is removed!
http://d.pr/i/oCr4

Comment: This works just great right now.
Can you please tell me what that second jquery part means ? I am with really low knowledge of jQuery.

Comment: I am glad that it worked. The second part is a jQuery plugin which you can use to remove all attributes from any element.

Answer (score 1):

You were eliminating `shortResize` class and then in next statement trying to select by it, see fixed version:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 70) {
        $('header').addClass('shortResize');
        $('.shortResize').animate({ 'opacity': '1' });
        $('section#contentWrap').addClass('contentWrap-margin');
    } else {
        $('.shortResize').css('opacity', '0'); //THIS NEEDS BE DONE FIRST
        $('header').removeClass('shortResize'); 
        $('section#contentWrap').removeClass('contentWrap-margin');
    }
});
```

Comment: I had a small typo mistake you should fix it too (sorry) :)
.css('opacity', '0');

However something just isn't right... It doesn't works this way either.